# multi-value attribute search and insert into another table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables with below structures.

TableA :
mo_code int,
description varchar(30)

[image: Table A data]

TableB :
dr_num int,
mo_codes varchar(30)  # comma seperated string which contains integers

[image: Table B data]

Now, I need to fetch the rows from TableA where mo_code in (select mo_code from TableB) and insert dr_num from TableB and mo_code from TableA into another table.

Any solution is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` with the help of `FIND_IN_SET`:

```sql
INSERT INTO otherTable (MO_Code, DR_Number)
SELECT a.MO_Code, b.DR_Number
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN TableB b
    ON FIND_IN_SET(a.MO_Code, b.MO_Codes) > 0;
```

By the way, it is general bad practice to store CSV in your SQL tables.  The above query should be viewed as a temporary workaround.  A better design would be to store each `MO_Code` on a separate record in the B table.